# FreeRadius dictionary loading

Tags: c, dictionary, client, radius, freeradius

I'm trying to load a dictionary that comes in with Debian Squeeze. Unfortunately radius-client library fails on some included file with:

```
rc_read_dictionary: unknown Vendor-Id encrypt=1 on line 7 of dictionary /usr/share/freeradius/dictionary.compat
```

The line is

```
ATTRIBUTE       Password                                2       string  encrypt=1
```

Freeradius is installed from the package, so I assume this should work just fine... What could be the problem here?

Comment: @sixlettervariables C, but that doesn't really matter here, I think. rc_read_dictionary comes from the radius-client API and it's already running.

Comment: Trying to add tags to get you eyes on the question.

Comment: What version of FreeRADIUS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but it still might help others, I got bit by a related issue.

You're getting that error because you're trying to use a dictionary file designed for the FreeRADIUS *server*.  The *client* library "freeradius-client" is not 100% compatible with that format.  Specifically, in your case, it cannot handle the `encrypt=1` property of the attribute.

The reason for the complaint about an unknown Vendor-Id is another incompatibility between FreeRADIUS server and the freeradius-client library.  FreeRADIUS server expects dictionary files with vendor specific attributes (VSAs) like the following:

```
VENDOR        Cisco           9
BEGIN-VENDOR  Cisco
ATTRIBUTE     Cisco-AVPair    1  string
ATTRIBUTE     Cisco-NAS-Port  2  string
...
END-VENDOR    Cisco
```

The freeradius-client library however can only parse VSAs in the following form:

```
VENDOR        Cisco           9
ATTRIBUTE     Cisco-AVPair    1  string  vendor=Cisco
ATTRIBUTE     Cisco-NAS-Port  2  string  vendor=Cisco
```

The above is true for FreeRADIUS server v2.1.x and freeradius-client v1.1.6.

Comment: I worked around the issue and probably won't test the solution, but there are many similar questions around the internet, so I hope someone else will find it useful in the future. Thanks! I believe it's correct.